# PHP Eclipse - Do not select $ when selecting PHP Variable

Tags: eclipse, phpeclipse

I have recently been using PHP Eclipse and have got everything set up the way i like it with just one exception.

When i double click on a variable it also highlights the $ which makes it difficult to move to the next occurrence if it is later used without the $ as part of $this as an example.

Does anybody know how or if this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Just use Ctrl-F and search for the exact text you want.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of this function.  I was wondering if it was possible to set it up per the way i described.